# Advanced Grammar and Style Checker

Tags: software-rec, documents, styles, english, grammar

I just finished writing and reviewing my masters thesis; however, I was wondering if there is an advanced grammar/style tool that'll go through my thesis and identify anything I've missed

Edit:

The tool(s) don't have to be opensource rather I'm looking for a semi reliable advanced grammar (not spell checker) checker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out http://www.paperrater.com/.  It pregrades your paper, highly recommend...just copy and paste!

Online, FREE, no registration, and offers suggestions, etc.

Comment: So many features for free, it's basically someone reading it and making suggestions, but you have to send your paper to them. I'm sensing a catch somewhere, since I can't see clearly their business model.

Comment: @Gnoupi, I've tried sending them a paper before, and they gave me the results within seconds...have yet to find a catch, at least to the extent that I used it.

Comment: withing seconds is not from an actual person, then, so I can see the point, I think. Free version is probably used to refine the program with different sources, in order to provide their later premium service.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.whitesmoke.com/products.html I haven't used it personally. Looks like they're running a special now, the software is about $100.

Answer (score -1):

OpenOffice and OpenOffice Addons. Check them out, there are really advanced spell checker tools. (You can use the Openoffice portable also. Extensions link: http://extensions.services.openoffice.org/ ) 
Best combination for spellchecking. :)

Comment: Where did I mention spell checking ? the tag was added on by someone else